# A Fundamental Question about MultiVariable Inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, polynomials

This is a question about a basic idea that we use to solve inequalities.

Suppose that you have an inequality to prove and the sides are two or three,... variables. Why is it so important if the sides don't have the same degree (  usually we see this in problems with conditions ) finding an equivalent inequality with same degree sides?

For example see this :

Let $ a,b,c,d $ be real numbers such that $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 = 4 $. Prove that $ a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3 \le 8 $

The way I approached was that square both sides to have degree 6 and somehow enter $ a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 $ in problem.

$ a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3 \le |a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3| $ and $ |a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3| \le 8 \Leftrightarrow (\Sigma a^6) + 2(a^3b^3+ a^3c^3+ ... +c^3d^3 ) \le 64 = (\Sigma{a^2})^3 = \Sigma{a^6} + 3(a^2b^2(a^2+b^2) + a^2c^2(a^2+c^2)+ ... + c^2d^2(c^2+d^2)) + 6(\Sigma{a^2b^2c^2}) $

which is equivalent to $ 2((a^2b^2)(a^2-ab+b^2) + ... + c^2d^2(c^2-cd+d^2)) + (a^2b^2(a^2+b^2) + a^2c^2(a^2+c^2)+ ... + c^2d^2(c^2+d^2)) + 6(\Sigma{a^2b^2c^2}) \ge 0 $ which is obviously true.

Here's another but very easy example:

If $ x+y+z = 1 $ Show that $ xy+yz+zx < \dfrac{1}{2} $

The idea is to write $ 1 = (x+y+z)^2 $ in orfer to have all the terms of degree $ 6 $ and then it's equivalent to prove $ 1 < 1 + x^2+y^2+z^2 $

Now the basic question that I have is what is beyond this Idea? Is there any algebraic or Analysis basis for this property of Multi variable Polynomials?

Here's The link of the same topic of mine in AOPS.com : https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1463175_a_fundamental_question_about_multivariable_inequalities

Answer (score 1):

Your first inequality and the general case follows from Karamata.

Indeed, we need to prove that $$\sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3}\leq\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}.$$
It's enough to prove the last inequality for non-negative variables.

Let $a\geq b\geq c\geq d$, $a^2=x$, $b^2=y$, $c^2=z$ and $d^2=t$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$(x+y+z+t)^{\frac{3}{2}}\geq x^{\frac{3}{2}}+y^{\frac{3}{2}}+z^{\frac{3}{2}}+t^{\frac{3}{2}},$$
which is obvious because $$(x+y+z+t,0,0,0)\succ(x,y,z,t)$$
and $f(x)=x^{\frac{3}{2}}$ is a convex function.